# VisualStudio2017-Qt5.12.3 - cannot add msvc2017_64

Tags: visual-studio-2017, qt

I want to build a Qt GUI app using VS2017, so I installed VS2017 and Qt5.12.3. And also the VS-Qt add-in.

But when I setup this, I can't add `msvc2017_64` into it. When I click "Add", there is an error window popping up:

[image: Here is the picture of the error]

The error message is in Chinese. In English it is

> The object reference is not set to an instance of the object.

I tried to reinstall Qt, but it doesn't work.
What should I do to add it successfully?

Comment: Try installing the proper MSVC2017 (based on your language) itself directly from the Visual Studio website.  Be sure to install the 32-bit and 64-but version

Comment: [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) is where you will find the proper installer

Comment: I had downloaded and installed it successfully,but the error is still here.